# bash: regular expressions in if expression

Tags: bash, regular-expression, distributions, test

In my script on my ubuntu machine I declare a string like this:

```
DEBUG_PACKAGE_LIST=$(apt-cache search dbg | awk '{ print $1 }' | grep -e "-dbg")
```

For you to help you understand my problem [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5AbqZgkm4cpU2lST0pmcXg0Qm8/edit?usp=sharing) is the output of

```
echo $DEBUG_PACKAGE_LIST >> debug
```

The following

```
if [[ ! $DEBUG_PACKAGE_LIST =~ "[^-a-z0-9]libmagick++5-dbg[a-z]*" ]]; then 
   echo "no contained"; 
fi
```

echos "not contained", despite `$DEBUG_PACKAGE_LIST` contains the string "libmagick++5-dbgsym". Could you help me understand why?

Basically my intention is to match libmagick++5-dbg, wheras, libmagick should only be preceeded by a space character.

Comment: `+` is an extended regex operator, and some (the recent ones) versions of `bash` don't treat regexp operators as operators when quoted.

Comment: You can also remove a pipe: `awk` handles pattern matching, `awk '/-dbg/ { print $1 }'`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash` 3.2 or above:

```
shopt -u compat31
[[ ! $DEBUG_PACKAGE_LIST =~ [^-[:alnum:]]'libmagick++5-dbg' ]];
```

In `bash` 3.1:

```
[[ ! $DEBUG_PACKAGE_LIST =~ '[^-[:alnum:]]libmagick\+\+5-dbg' ]];
```

(note that `[a-z]*` is redundant since it also matches the empty string so will always match).

Works in both:

```
re='[^-[:alnum:]]libmagick\+\+5-dbg'
[[ ! $DEBUG_PACKAGE_LIST =~ $re ]]
```

Comment: Thanks sir, `[^-[:alnum:]]` was exactly what I need! Do you have a link to good documentation? BTW: `if [[ ! $DEBUG_PACKAGE_LIST =~ [^-[:alnum:]]"libmagick++5-dbg" ]];then echo "not contained";fi` works here without problems. I need the quote because libmagick++5 is only an example here, there is an variable $package in my script.

Answer (score 0):

**[You can't quote the regular expression](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5B.5B_.24foo_.3D.2BAH4_.27some_RE.27_.5D.5D)** on the right of such an expression (unless you're using a [Bash version](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges#conditional_expressions_and_test_command) >= 3.0-alpha and < 3.2-alpha). If you do, it's treated as a comparison between literal strings.

Also, Bash uses [extended regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04) for `=~`, where `+` is a special character.

Comment: Depends on the version of `bash` (and on the `compat31` option in newer bash versions).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a shell pattern, rather than a regular expression. Prepend a space to the string so that you don't need to treat the first element differently from the others.

```
if [[ " $DEBUG_PACKAGE_LIST" = *\ libmagick++5-dbg[a-z]* ]]; then
```

(Are you sure about the mandatory letter after `-dbg`? The package name ends with `-dbg`.)